# How do I compare time in bash?

Tags: bash, time, compare

So this is my simple script that I'm trying to work in automator on mac. If time is more than 6PM and less than 6AM, it will switch on my TP-Link Plug.

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +%k)
echo $now
if (( $now > 18 && $now < 6));then
    /Volumes/Work/VM/tplon.sh
    echo yay!
else
    echo nay!
    /Volumes/Work/VM/tploff.sh
fi
```

I'm not very handson with programming but do it more like a hobby sometimes when I need it.

The output of this script is: (when tried last at about 4AM)

```
4
nay!
```

No matter what I try, the execution always jumps to the else condition.
Help?

Comment: The time is never both more than 18 and less than 6. You want `||`

Comment: wow! that was easy! thanks!